# Option<Receiver> Moved in Previous Loop Iteration

Tags: rust, spawn, borrow-checker, receiver

I'm spawning a thread that does some work. Sometimes I want this thread to die after the work is finished, other times I want it to wait for more work to do. To do this I pass in an `Option<Receiver<T>>`. If `Option<Receiver<T>>` is `None` the thread should die, else it should wait to receive more work.

```
fn foo(rx: Option<Receiver<usize>>) {
    thread::spawn(move || {
        loop {
            do_some_work();
            if let Some(r) = rx {
                match r.recv() {
                    Ok(x)  => {}
                    Err(_) => panic!("Oh no!"),
                }
            } else {
                break; //Die
            }
        }
    });
}
```

([link to playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=daf93b80174e754b2202ef7c02ef993a))

The compiler says:

```
error[E0382]: use of moved value
  --> src/lib.rs:10:25
   |
10 |             if let Some(r) = rx {
   |                         ^ value moved here, in previous iteration of loop
   |
   = note: move occurs because value has type `std::sync::mpsc::Receiver<usize>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

However if the `Receiver` is not enclosed in an `Option` everything is fine.

```
fn foo(rx: Receiver<usize>) {
    thread::spawn(move || {
        loop {
            do_some_work();
            match rx.recv() {
                Ok(x)  => {}
                Err(_) => panic!("Oh no!"),
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: In the first case, if you call `foo(None)`, it starts a thread, enters the loop, fails the test, breaks the loop, stops the thread. Why even start a thread then? Are you sure you don't want `Receiver<Option<usize>>`? This would seem to make more sense.

Comment: @mcarton I posted a trimmed down thread. The `//Does work` comment represents a significant amount of work that isn't shown. If a new `usize` is passed in the thread will adjust some parameters and redo the work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you write `if let Some(r) = rx`, you consume `rx`, making it unavailable for later.

You can use `as_ref()` to get a reference to the inner object instead, leaving `rx` usable:

```rust
fn foo(rx: Option<Receiver<usize>>) {
    thread::spawn(move || {
        loop {
            do_some_work();
            if let Some(r) = rx.as_ref() {
                match r.recv() {
                    Ok(x) => {}
                    Err(_) => panic!("Oh no!"),
                }
            } else {
                break; //Die
            }
        }
    });
}
```

([link to playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=8003544aff36cdec00953aaadb70f3f2))

Comment: or just `&rx`, don't we have duplicate for this ?